# # not rendering HTML heading tags after GitHub's recent update for pages and Jekyll

Tags: github, markdown, jekyll, github-pages, kramdown

This week, [GitHub announced that it will *only* support kramdown](https://github.com/blog/2100-github-pages-now-faster-and-simpler-with-jekyll-3-0) for its product [Pages](https://pages.github.com/).

Per their suggestion - I [removed `markdown: redcarpet`](https://github.com/xameeramir/xameeramir.github.io/commit/f700fa5cbcf5f65b355b44197558bc0b2f2550a3) and updated [`highlighter` value to `rouge`](https://github.com/xameeramir/xameeramir.github.io/commit/db0f42108322323a564407ca39075538d94c6eb3) in the [_config](https://github.com/xameeramir/xameeramir.github.io/blob/master/_config.yml) of [my project](https://github.com/xameeramir/xameeramir.github.io).

Now the only problem is that `#` is unable to render as a heading on any of the pages on the [main website](http://xameeramir.github.io/)

- What is the workaround for this?

> side question: Is there anything else to watch out for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Github have enabled [kramdown’s GFM parser](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/parser/gfm.html) by default in the update to Pages. One of the changes this parser makes is to require whitespace between the `#` and the text of the header for it to be considered as a header.

I don’t know if you are able to change this default back in your configuration. The [Jekyll docs](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/#kramdown) describe how to change *to* GFM, but not how to set it to any other parser, and even if there was a way it’s possible Github overrides it anyway.

You might have to change your headers to add the space. e.g. change all lines that look something like this:

```
#Focus on user
```

to:

```
# Focus on user
```

Comment: [This will be too much work man](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/4481#event-541824422) :( `#`s are almost everywhere

Comment: And if you had been following the rules all along, you would not have any work to do now.

Comment: @student According to https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages/ you should be able to change the GFM setting. I think you should be able to do `input: kramdown` under the `kramdown:` options of your config.

Answer (score 1):

As for your

> side question: Is there anything else to watch out for?

Yes, you'll need to pay attention to a few things:

- [dropped gem dependencies](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/upgrading/2-to-3/#dropped-dependencies): some gems are no longer required by default and will need to be added to the configuration file and to your Gemfile if you want to use them;
- they changed the way of calling [collections](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/upgrading/2-to-3/#sitecollections-has-changed) individually;
- they changed the way to setting [permalinks](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/upgrading/2-to-3/#permalinks-no-longer-automatically-add-a-trailing-slash);
- they introduced some new features, as [`future` posts](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/upgrading/2-to-3/#future-posts) and [`layout` metadata](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/upgrading/2-to-3/#layout-metadata);

Hope to have helped! ;)

Comment: Thanks for your inputs!